# What would be the success criteria for user testing for 2FA authentication

Tags: usability, mobile-application, usability-testing, security, authentication

i'm conducting a user testing session for a few prototypes. one of the prototypes of a feature i'll be testing is the 2 factor authentication.

Compared to other features which have more of an information or value element, 2FA seems to be a more of a security and intermediate feature.

i'd like to know what factors should i be testing for and the questions i should be asking for this feature. Some factors i'm considering are

1. Does the user perceive their app environment is secure after 2FA authentication
2. Ease of use for users to get authenticated with 2FA (on a scale of 1-10)
3. Clarity of error messages when users encountered them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The questions you are asking are geared more towards a survey and that would be my method of getting the answer the Qs you are proposing.

If a survey is too blunt, then simply monitoring the number of users who are signing in using 2FA, in comparison to those who have started the process and not completed it, those whom have read information and not proceeded and those whom continue to ignore the offer, then you could reach out to those people to understand what the blockers are to using the service.

Answer (score 0):

You can monitor time from page load to successful log in.

To successfully measure something you need a baseline and a way to measure it over time.

Here's a article by [nngroup](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/calculating-roi-design-projects/) with several examples of how to measure a metric in UX:

It even mentions `Ease-of-use rating` in Surveys.

hope it helps.

Comment: Please expand on this answer, as it is it's more of a comment than an answer.